# updating a mongo database to have all items show current date in correct format

Tags: mongodb, date, mongodb-query, updates

I am working to update all of the drinks in my mongo database to have the current date.  Right now they are all empty strings.

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("558c51479707e56c48b16ec0"),
    "caffeineLevel" : "23",
    "date" : "",
    "name" : "Choffy (roasted cacao)",
    "editable" : false
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("558c51479707e56c48b16ec1"),
    "caffeineLevel" : "170",
    "date" : "",
    "name" : "Cintron Energy Drink",
    "editable" : false
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("558c51479707e56c48b16ec2"),
    "caffeineLevel" : "100",
    "date" : "",
    "name" : "Clif Shot Turbo Energy Gel",
    "editable" : false
}
```

I read through the documents on mongodb and have set my update to this ..

```js
db.drinks.update({},{$set: {'date': Date.now()}}, false,true)
```

- I read to start with an empty object so that all the collections are updated.
- I am targeting the date object so I am looking to set the date to `Date.now()`

But when I pushed it in to terminal I my date was set at `1436156620169`  for each date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [**`new Date()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Date/#date) instead

```js
db.drinks.update( {}, { $set: { 'date': new Date() }}, false, true )
```

Comment: Thanks for catching that.  I did not see what I was doing

Comment: @stevek glad to have been of help. Feel free to accept the answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

your update command has updated the date with the epoch time, if you want another format then use functions mentioned here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date